# How to debug why 'systemctl hibernate' works, but 'systemctl suspend-then-hibernate' not?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, systemd, hibernate

My current setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1
- Encrypted partition with an LVM2 on it.
- LMV

  - root (/dev/mapper/it--vg-root)
  - swap (/dev/mapper/it--vg-swap_1)
- Random cryptswap that maps to /dev/dm-3, whatever that might be, that seems to be gone now.

What have I done:

- Changed the swap for the system to `/dev/mapper/it--vg-swap_1` via fstab
- Changed the UUID in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` to the new swap partition and ran `sudo update-initramfs -u`
- Added `resume=UUID=XXXXXXX` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` variable with the UUID of the new swap partition and ran `sudo update-grub`
- I created a file `/etc/systemd/sleep.conf` with the following content:

  ```
  [Sleep]
  HibernateDelaySec=10
  ```
- I rebooted the whole system

Then I tested two cases:

1. `systemctl hibernate`

The system goes to hibernation properly. It boots back up, asks me for the decryption password and opens up all the windows and applications that I had open before.

2. `systemctl suspend-then-hibernate`

The systemd goes to suspend mode. My power key indicates that by blinking.
After around ten seconds (mind the config in `sleep.conf`) it turns back on and the screen goes to a blinking terminal cursor.
Then it goes down to what seems to be hibernation.

No indications that the system is still on. After pressing the power button the system comes back up, asking for the encryption key and continues to boot like it should after I typed it in.

After logging in all previously opened applications are not open anymore. Everything is closed and lost.

It seems like the computer was either shut down completely or the ram that was dumped after suspension was in fact empty, because the suspension already dumped it to the swap partition.

But those are just random theories.

My question is: how would I be able to debug this problem and find the problem?

If you have an answer to why this happening, I would take that, too :)

Comment: @Terrance I ran it without `-k all` (update my question). But I only use one kernel, so that should be fine. I'll try it anyway ;)

Comment: That shouldn't matter then.  It only will apply to the running kernel.  You just didn't have it at the time of my comment.  I have all the settings correct on my system and the `suspend-then-hibernate` causes a massive non-responsive host to me.  Wonder if it is a bug.

Comment: Tried it. Sadly it did not make any difference. Though my system responses fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

As on Ubuntu 20.04 (systemd 245) you have also to include the following line under the sleep section:

```
AllowSuspend=yes
AllowHibernation=yes
AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
```

Further are you sure that you want to go into hibernate state after 10 seconds in suspend state?

Comment: The 10 seconds were for testing purposes only ;_)